# GraphDatabase API how to deal with neo4j logging

Tags: api, logging, neo4j

Hi, I am trying to run a query using the following :

```
final GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDatabaseService,StringLogger.DEV_NULL);
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("START n=node(0) RETURN n");
```

However, an exception is fired upon executiong the upon code :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   scala/Function0

Can you give me advises on how to solve this issue, anyone ever had the same one ?

Thanks.

Comment: Embedded graph databases don't work with remote URLs, use something like http://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding e.g. `new RestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data").query(query, params)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-rest-graphdb</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.M04</version>
</dependency>
```

Then use it in your java-code like this:

```
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPI;
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade;
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.query.RestCypherQueryEngine;
import org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.QueryResult;

import java.util.Map;

import static org.neo4j.helpers.collection.MapUtil.map;

public class RestApiTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final RestAPI api = new RestAPIFacade("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
        final RestCypherQueryEngine engine = new RestCypherQueryEngine(api);
        final QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> result = engine.query("start n=node({id}) return n.name, id(n) as id", map("id", 0));
        for (Map<String, Object> row : result) {
            long id=((Number)row.get("id")).longValue();
            String name= (String) row.get("n.name");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but when you use the rest API you might as well just use the Core API to do the stuff you need to do. With embedded databases, the use of the core API is so much faster than Cypher so I'd expect the same from the rest API though I have not tested this yet. Also, I'm not sure but I think class RestAPI doesn't have the same functionalities as GraphDatabaseService, which is also an interface for RestAPIFacade. I tend to use the latter.